# Что делает эта строка в структуре

Tags: c, структуры, дерево

Пишу АВЛ-дерево

[Везде](https://habr.com/post/150732/) пишут подобную структуру

```
struct node // структура для представления узлов дерева
{
    int key;
    unsigned char height;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node(int k) { key = k; left = right = 0; height = 1; }
};
```

И пояснение:

> Поле key хранит ключ узла, поле height — высоту поддерева с корнем в данном узле, поля left и right — указатели на левое и правое поддеревья. Простой конструктор создает новый узел (высоты 1) с заданным ключом k.

Но я не совсем понимаю, что делает эта строка:

```
node(int k) { key = k; left = right = 0; height = 1; }
```

Можете объяснить?

Спасибо!

Comment: Инициализирует узел. Это - **конструктор** класса (структура и класс в С++ - одно и то же, просто у структуры по умолчанию все поля открыты).

Comment: @Harry я СИ лучше знаю. Можете объяснить более простым языком.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная строка - конструктор языке С++. Если вы хотите писать АВЛ-дерево используя язык Си, то вам необходимо написать функцию-инициализатор для узла node. Примерно данный конструктор в процедурном программировании будет выглядеть как :

```
void init_node(node* nd, int key)
{
  nd->key = k;
  nd->left = nd->right = NULL;
  nd->height = 1;
}
```

Comment: Ооооо - спасибо, добрый человек